# Is it safe to leave cut wires on a rotary phone circuit board?

Tags: bad-wiring

I'm trying to make an audio guestbook for my wedding using a rotary telephone. A tutorial showed what wires I need, so I assumed the rest of the wires on the circuit board, I could get rid of.

I snipped any unnecessary wires with a pair of scissors. Is this dangerous?

Once I have finished working on the phone and give it power, will these snipped and exposed wires be a hazard? I have snipped the wires in two places:

1. Where they are soldered on the circuit board.
2. The parts of the phone they were connecting to.

Technically there are 8 exposed and snipped wires on the circuit board. The image below only shows 4 of them.

[image: Cut wires on circuit board]

Comment: The snipped wires are on connectors which you can just unplug.  You could unplug or snip close if you think there's any chance they might touch each other.  But no, there's no real hazard.

Comment: "I snipped any unnecessary wires with a pair of scissors. Is this dangerous?" are they sewing scissors? It could involve physical danger..

Answer (score 1):

The only hazard of cutting wires with scissors is that the scissor blades are now likely ruined and have notches that won't go away with sharpening.

The cut wires inside a phone are likely not a hazard to any humans.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that the exposed wire doesn't touch any other metal surface. If you are concerned, you could use electrical tape or hot glue to isolate them.

Another concern if you cut these with plain scissors is that you might shove the shield (metallic outer layer) down towards the wires and create a short. For hobbyist purposes I'd rather recommend cutting with garden secateurs. Unplug the voltage before you cut, obviously. Then inspect the cut so that no metal parts are touching each other by accident.

Comment: these don't look like shielded cables to me

Comment: @user253751 I can't tell from the pic, but the same concern applies for any two wires in the cable, especially if they are multi-strand ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Lundin!